# Enable to read data from firestore database but can write with flutter riverpod

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have this project which enable me to read and write from firestore database with flutter riverpod. But now i can only write but cannot read. I started having this problem when i updated the dependences and this massage came up.

pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.9.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestoreMessageCodec.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

i have googled but did not find any solution. It too me to this pub.dev
cloud_firestore 4.9.1 icon indicating copy to clipboard operation
Published 19 days ago • verified publisher iconfirebase.google.comDart 3 compatible
SDKFLUTTERPLATFORMANDROIDIOSMACOSWEB
3.0K
Readme
Changelog
Example
Installing
Versions
Scores
4.9.1
FIX(cloud_firestore): Fix crashes on iOS/macOS (#11501). (3ed53470)
4.9.0
FEAT(firestore): add support for multiple database instances (#11310). (ce6efcc1)
4.8.5
FIX(firestore): allow FieldPath.documentId as a field argument in queries (#11443). (4e01a9d8)
4.8.4
FIX(firestore): remove assertion for arrayContainsAny & whereIn query combined (#11342)

```
this my repository
final forumRepositoryProvider = Provider((ref) {
  return ForumRepository(firestore: ref.watch(firestoreProvider));
});

class ForumRepository {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore;
  ForumRepository({required FirebaseFirestore firestore})
      : _firestore = firestore;

  FutureVoid createForum(ForumModel forumModel) async {
    try {
      var forumDoc = await _forums.doc(forumModel.name).get();
      if (forumDoc.exists) {
        throw 'Forum with the same name already exist';
      }
      return right(
          _forums.doc(forumModel.name).set(forumModel.toMap()));
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.message!));
    } catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.toString()));
    }
  } 

  Stream<List<ForumModel>> getUserForum(String uid) {
    return _forums
        .where('members', arrayContains: uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map((event) {
      List<ForumModel> forums = [];
      for (var doc in event.docs) {
        forums
            .add(ForumModel.fromMap(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
      }
      return forums;
    });
  }

  Stream<ForumModel> getForumByName(String name) {
    return _forums.doc(name).snapshots().map((event) =>
        ForumModel.fromMap(event.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
  }

  Either<Failure, dynamic> editForum(ForumModel forumModel) {
    try {
      return right(
          _forums.doc(forumModel.name).update(forumModel.toMap()));
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      throw e.message!;
    } catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.toString()));
    }
  }

  FutureVoid joinForum(String forumName, String userId) async {
    try {
      return right(_forums.doc(forumName).update({
        'members': FieldValue.arrayUnion([userId])
      }));
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      throw e.message!;
    } catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.toString()));
    }
  }

  FutureVoid leaveForum(String forumName, String userId) async {
    try {
      return right(_forums.doc(forumName).update({
        'members': FieldValue.arrayRemove([userId])
      }));
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      throw e.message!;
    } catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.toString()));
    }
  }

  Stream<List<ForumModel>> searchForum(String query) {
    return _forums
        .where(
          'name',
          isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: query.isEmpty ? 0 : query,
          isLessThan: query.isEmpty
              ? null
              : query.substring(0, query.length - 1) +
                  String.fromCharCode(
                    query.codeUnitAt(query.length - 1) + 1,
                  ),
        )
        .snapshots()
        .map((event) {
      List<ForumModel> forums = [];
      for (var forumModel in event.docs) {
        forums.add(ForumModel.fromMap(
            forumModel.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
      }
      return forums;
    });
  }

  Either<Failure, dynamic> addMods(String forumName, List<String> uids) {
    try {
      return right(_forums.doc(forumName).update({
        'mods': uids,
      }));
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      throw e.message!;
    } catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.toString()));
    }
  }

  Stream<List<Upload>> getForumUploads(String name) {
    return _uploads
        .where('forumName', isEqualTo: name)
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map(
          (event) => event.docs
              .map(
                (e) => Upload.fromMap(
                  e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>,
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        );
  }

  CollectionReference get _uploads =>
      _firestore.collection(FirebaseConstants.uploadCollection);

  CollectionReference get _forums =>
      _firestore.collection(FirebaseConstants.forumCollection);

  //    CollectionReference get _groups =>
  //    _firestore.collection(FirebaseConstants.groupCollection);
}
this is the controller

final userForumProvider = StreamProvider((ref) {
  final forumController = ref.watch(forumControllerProvider.notifier);
  return forumController.getUserForums();
});

final forumControllerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<ForumController, bool>((ref) {
  final forumRepository = ref.watch(forumRepositoryProvider);
  final storageRepository = ref.watch(storageRepositoryProvider);
  return ForumController(
    forumRepository: forumRepository,
    storageRepository: storageRepository,
    ref: ref,
  );
});

final getForumByNameProvider = StreamProvider.family((ref, String name) {
  return ref.watch(forumControllerProvider.notifier).getForumByName(name);
});

final searchForumProvider = StreamProvider.family((ref, String query) {
  return ref.watch(forumControllerProvider.notifier).searchForum(query);
});

//final getForumUploadsProvider = StreamProvider.family((ref, String name) {
// return ref.read(forumControllerProvider.notifier).getForumUploads(name);
//});

class ForumController extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  final ForumRepository _forumRepository;
  final Ref _ref;
  final StorageRepository _storageRepository;

  ForumController({
    required ForumRepository forumRepository,
    required Ref ref,
    required StorageRepository storageRepository,
  })  : _forumRepository = forumRepository,
        _ref = ref,
        _storageRepository = storageRepository,
        super(false);

  void creatForum(String name, description, BuildContext context) async {
    state = true;
    final uid = _ref.read(userProvider)?.uid ?? '';
    ForumModel forumModel = ForumModel(
      id: name,
      name: name,
      description: description,
      banner: Constants.bannerDefault,
      avatar: Constants.avatarDefault,
      members: [uid],
      admin: [uid],
      timeSent: DateTime.now(),
    );

    final res = await _forumRepository.createForum(forumModel);
    state = false;
    res.fold((l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message), (r) {
      showSnackBar(context, 'Forum created successfully');
      Routemaster.of(context).pop();
    });
  }

 
  void joinForum(ForumModel forumModel, BuildContext context) async {
    final user = _ref.read(userProvider)!;

    Either<Failure, void> res;

    if (forumModel.members.contains(user.uid)) {
      res = await _forumRepository.leaveForum(forumModel.name, user.uid);
    } else {
      res = await _forumRepository.joinForum(forumModel.name, user.uid);
    }
    res.fold((l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message), (r) {
      if (forumModel.members.contains(user.uid)) {
        showSnackBar(context, 'Forum left successfully');
      } else {
        showSnackBar(context, 'Forum join successfullly');
      }
    });
  }

  Stream<List<ForumModel>> getUserForums() {
    final uid = _ref.read(userProvider)!.uid;
    return _forumRepository.getUserForum(uid);
  }

  Stream<ForumModel> getForumByName(String name) {
    return _forumRepository.getForumByName(name);
  }

  void editForum({
    required Uint8List? profileFile,
    required Uint8List? bannerFile,
    required BuildContext context,
    required ForumModel forumModel,
  }) async {
    state = true;
    if (profileFile != null) {
      //communities/profile/memes
      final res = await _storageRepository.storeFile(
        path: 'forum/profile',
        id: forumModel.name,
        file: profileFile,
      );
      res.fold(
        (l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message),
        (r) => forumModel = forumModel.copyWith(
          avatar: r,
        ),
      );
    }
    if (bannerFile != null) {
      //communities/banner/memes
      final res = await _storageRepository.storeFile(
        path: 'forum/banner',
        id: forumModel.name,
        file: bannerFile,
      );
      res.fold(
        (l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message),
        (r) => forumModel = forumModel.copyWith(
          banner: r,
        ),
      );
    }
    final res = await _forumRepository.editForum(forumModel);
    state = false;
    res.fold(
      (l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message),
      (r) => Routemaster.of(context).pop(),
    );
  }

  Stream<List<ForumModel>> searchForum(String query) {
    return _forumRepository.searchForum(query);
  }

  void addMods(
      String forumName, List<String> uids, BuildContext context) async {
    final res = await _forumRepository.addMods(forumName, uids);
    res.fold(
      (l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message),
      (r) => Routemaster.of(context).pop(),
    );
  }

  // Stream<List<Upload>> getForumUploads(String name) {
  //   return _forumRepository.getForumUploads(name);
  // }
}

and this is the code that display the list

class ForumList extends ConsumerWidget {
  final String name;
  const ForumList({super.key,
    required this.name,
  });

  void navigateToCreateForum(BuildContext context) {
    Routemaster.of(context).push('/create-forum');
  }

  void navigateToForum(BuildContext context, ForumModel forumModel) {
    Routemaster.of(context) .push('${forumModel.name}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ListTile(
            title: const Text('Create a forum',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                )),
            leading: const Icon(
              Icons.add,
              size: 30,
            ),
            onTap: () => navigateToCreateForum(context),
          ),
          ref.watch(userForumProvider).when(
                data: (forums) => Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: forums.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      final forumModel = forums[index];
                      return ListTile(
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(forumModel.avatar),
                        ),
                        title: Text('${forumModel.name}',
                            style:
                                const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        onTap: (() {
                         // navigateToChatScreen(context, forumModel);
                           navigateToForum(context, forumModel);
                        }),
                        subtitle: Text('${forumModel.description}'),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                error: (error, stackTrace) =>
                    ErrorText(error: error.toString()),
                loading: (() => const Loader()),
              ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```